# Sum the base elements of a randomly nested array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

Given a multidimensional array of integers, how can I find the sum of all the base elements? Each array may have a different number of arrays in it, so my algorithm must be flexible to accommodate all possible inputs. A recursive method would seem to be the most elegant solution. Example:

**Given:**

```
array = {
   {{1,2,3},
   {4,5},
   {6,7,8}},
   {{9},{10}}
}
```

**Return**:
`55`

Note that the length of each sub-array is inconsistent and varies, as well as the depth of the array. This means that traditional loops would not be able to check the length of the array, and recursive methods would not be able to define the number of dimensions the loop has as an initial parameter. Perhaps a recursive loop would need to cast an `Object` as an array?

---

**Edit:**

The method should also be able to sum an array of ANY number of dimensions. For example, the input array could have three dimensions, or even 7.

Comment: provide an output of what do you expect with the above given input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Java Streams you can use just this (assuming your array has 2 dimensions):

```
int[][] array = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {9, 10}};
int sum = Arrays.stream(array)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .sum();
```

If your array has 3 dimensions you can extend this to the following:

```
int[][][] array = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}, {{9}, {10}}};
int sum = Arrays.stream(array)
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .sum();
```

To handle arrays with unknown depth you can use this method to flatten them:

```
private static Stream<Object> flatMapDynamicArray(Object[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .flatMap(o -> o.getClass().isArray() ? 
                    flatMapDynamicArray((Object[]) o) : 
                    Stream.of(o));
}
```

You also could use `o instanceof Object[]` instead of `o.getClass().isArray()` but for my tests the second one had better performance.

Use this method like this:

```
Integer[][][] array = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}, {{9}, {10}}};
int sum = flatMapDynamicArray(array)
        .mapToInt(i -> (int) i)
        .sum();
```

The result in all cases will be `55` for the array you shared.

Comment: What if you do not know the number of dimensions the parent array will have?

Comment: So you have an `Object` as input?

Comment: Yes, `Object` would be an input, if necessary.

Comment: @FrankFanelli I edited my question. Hope it helps to handle arrays with unknown depths.

Comment: We can use `o.getClass().isArray()` instead of `o instanceof Object[]`.

Comment: @OmidNejadabbasi Yes, thanks for noticing. I tested it and updated my answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility which does not use streams or lambdas is to write a simple recursive method.  Just like others of this nature, type conflicts would only manifest themselves at runtime.

For the following nested array structure:

```java
      Integer[][][][] array = { { { { 1, 2, 3
            }, { 4, 5, 6
            }, { 7, 8, 9
            }
            }, { { 10, 11, 12,
            }, { 13, 14, 15
            }, { 16, 17, 19
            }
            }
            }, { { { 20, 21, 22
            }, { 23, 24, 25
            }
            }
            }
      };
```

```java
   System.out.println(sum(array));

   public static int sum(Object[] a) {
      int sum = 0;
      for (Object o : a) {
         if (o instanceof Object[]) {
            sum += sum((Object[]) o);
         }
         if (o instanceof Integer) {
            sum += (Integer) o;
         }
      }
      return sum;
   }
```

Prints

> 307